# JWS application doesn't respond to Swing button actions

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start

Why doesn't my JWS application respond to Swing button actions?

I have a program I created in eclipse. It collects information about devices connected to a local network and displays it in a `JTable`.  In the environment it executes fine
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS3Rk.png)  and [after the start button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmbIo.png)

When trying to launch it through Java Web Start (JWS), I press buttons on the Swing Gui and they do not perform the action method I created. It doesn't do anything.  Here is [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm3o5.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9xFm.png)

The jar/jnlp files are up to date and are being launched locally. What could cause this? How can I debug something like this?

Comment: *"Why doesn't my JWS Application respond to Swing actions?"*  Doesn't it?  Do you have a small, sand-boxed version we can test?  BTW - are you referring to key binding, or abstract actions or..?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I cannot provide the code, Ill try to get some screen caps

Comment: *"I cannot provide the code,"*  Note that an SSCCE is not 'the code'.

Comment: @aaronbobaron then everything here will be guessing only

Comment: @aaronbobaron What is it doing on pressing `start`?

Comment: @mKorbel How can I debug something like this then?

Comment: @VishalK It collects information about devices connected to a local network and displays it in a jTable.

Comment: [before anything to check if meets](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) made by @Andrew Thompson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When trying to launch it through Java Web Start (JWS),I press buttons
>   on the Swing Gui and they do not perform the action method I created.
>   It doesnt do anything.

As mentioned in [java-web-start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) tag in StackOverflow

> *By default, an applet-like security sand-box is applied to code
>   launched using JWS*

While, In your code as you had said , You are *collecting information about devices connected to a local network* . But , since your code is running in applet-like security sand-box it is not allowing it to access the local network which usually is allowed when you running it as desktop application via eclipse . So, when the `Start Test` button is clicked your application might be throwing some kind of `SecurityException` which is not anticipated by you , hence consumed in the background.

**UPDATE**

> To relax this sand-box the code needs to be digitally signed by the
>   provider, and trusted by the end user

This means that To make Your Code to perform those tasks which it can't do, you need to have the jnlp/jar file which is digitally signed by the provider from where you have downloaded it , and also you must be able to verify that the file is received from that site only and was not modified.This is to ensure that you the receiver doesn't run some malicious code which could harm his local system. See the oracle tutorial on [Lesson: API and Tools Use for Secure Code and File Exchanges](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/sigcert/index.html). It says that:

> If you electronically send someone an important document (or
>   documents), or an applet or application to run, the recipient needs a
>   way to verify that the document or code came from you and was not
>   modified in transit (for example, by a malicious user intercepting it)

There are many more information available on that tutorial. Go through it.

Comment: I decided this isn't really the route I want to take with this program but thank you regardless

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yeah..and thanks for the well documented info :) as mKorbel told that it is provided by you. Just wanna ask you something that where I can get the sample of signed Jar files?